# Convert WebDriver promise to native promise?

Tags: selenium, typescript, webdriver, protractor

I have this method:

```
isOnPage(): Promise<boolean> {
  return this.subtitle.isPresent();
}
```

The typescript compiler gives this error:

```
Type 'webdriver.promise.Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<boolean>'
```

Is there a way to convert a WebDriver promise to a native promise?

Would this work?

```
isOnPage(): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise(() => {
    return this.subtitle.isPresent();
  });
}
```

Comment: `webdriver.promise.Promise` is a different type than the native `Promise`.

Comment: Why do you need to convert to a native promise?

Comment: Team gets confused when there are multiple promise implementations in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip declaring return type this is case. This will still show you correct suggestions for return value

```
isOnPage() {
   return this.subtitle.isPresent();
}
```

Comment: Is this best practice? Seems like a decent idea.

Comment: Not a big fan of this solution. Regardless of the declared return type, it will still have the same inferred return type. Theoretically you could run into problems if you expected it to behave like a ES6 `Promise`, as they have different contracts.

Comment: I also think that it is better to explicitly specify returning type. I would be thankful for code example that works!

Comment: use `webdriver.promise.Promise<any>` as the return type.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { promise } from 'selenium-webdriver';

...

isOnPage(): promise.Promise<boolean> {
    return this.subtitle.isPresent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@types/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts` exports namespace `promise` with a class `Promise` that implements `PromiseLike` (not `Promise`).

`PromiseLike` seems to be a native implementation in `typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts` so you can use it as a return type for your function. The difference seems to be that `PromiseLike` only has `then` whereas `Promise` has `then` and `catch`.

```
isOnPage(): PromiseLike<boolean> {
  return this.subtitle.isPresent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer native promises as well and convert to them by using:

```
isOnPage(): Promise<boolean> {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    return this.subtitle.isPresent();
  });
}
```

This allows to write code like this:

```
it('should display cookie title and remove after click', (done) => {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      return browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    }).then(() => {
      return page.navigateTo();
    }).then(() => {
      //return E2eUtil.TakeScreenshot('CookiesidebarPage.png');
    }).then(() => {
      return expect(page.getTitleText()).toEqual('Cookies');
    }).then(() => {
      return page.clickAcceptCookies();
    }).then(() => {
      return page.waitTitleInvisible();
    }).then(() => {
      return expect(page.getTitleText()).toEqual('');
    }).then(() => {
      done();
    });
  });
```